# `part:` modifier in node import statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-next, sanity

I came across this code in a javascript / Node project but can't find any explanation online as to what it is and how it works.

```js
import PatchEvent, {set, unset} from 'part:@sanity/form-builder/patch-event';
```

Comment: yep, googling `part:@sanity` led me to sanitys docs and the have a page all about it. looks like they parse that stuff out using webpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this syntax is specific to sanity.io's platform and isn't proper node / javascript syntax

https://www.sanity.io/docs/parts

Comment: This is the right answer. Also note that an upcoming version of Sanity will use something else that doesn't require a non-standard import syntax.